# asp.net web app not loading in browser, not being found by project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am building a frontend for a web API. My sole issue I'm having so far is that whether I load up a brand new project using razor, etc; or I use my existing; or I find one out on GitHub that's confirmed working- **I cannot get the webpage to display.**

At first I was getting a blank screen that the "inspect" tool in my browser was showing that nothing was even loading aside form the HTML and body tags. Now I'm getting a page saying "cannot find 'index.cshtml' in Pages\Index.cshtml, Pages\Shared\Index.cshtml, or Pages\Home\Index.cshtml

My code is in these listed places.

I tried removing everything related to HTTPSRedirect from my program.cs/startup.cs which finally allows me to load the error data (I know this isn't a solution, just a step of troubleshooting i've done). I've tried ensuring my browser will allow the self signed certificate. **I've tried loading fresh data from a "hello world" default - with the same results**

`startup.cs` below

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Triangular.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`program.cs` below

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace Triangular.Web
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

`HomeController.cs` below

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Triangular.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("/Pages/Index.cshtml");
        }
    }
}
```

My Index.cshtml is located at `/Pages/Index.cshtml` and is currently the same default code as if you created a fresh, new Web App project.

- Using Visual Studio 2022 community
- .NET 6.0
- Browser: up to date Firefox, also tried Edge

I am able to replicate this issue by creating a brand new project and just launching that brand new project directly.

Comment: Check your VS 2022 installer. In VS goto tools -> Get tools and Features (I'm using Visual studio 2022 Prof). Is ASP.net and web development checked? Try to create a new project, File -> new -> Project, and select ASP.NET Core Web App. (Don't select .NET Framework). Just hit next (note the .NET version), and create. You still get the same error when trying to run this?

Comment: Also note that .NET Framework is different than .NET. There is no such thing as .NET Framework 6. It is .NET 6 or .NET 7 you should be using for new projects. The new .NET default templates that Visual Studio creates for you doesn't look like the code you posted. There is no Startup.cs, and Program.cs uses Top-Level statements.

Answer (score 0):

To have some .cshtml content served, the quickest way is to use ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. If I understood you correctly that is your current intent as well. You need to enable Razor Pages services in your application startup.

To do so you need to add `services.AddRazorPages();` to your `Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection)` method.

Then you need to enable some more ASP.NET Core services. Call the `app.UseStaticFiles();`, `app.UseRouting();`, and `app.UseEndpoints(IEndpointRouteBuilder);` methods in your `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment)` method.

Your `Startup.cs` file should look something similar after the additions:

```csharp
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Triangular.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            // ...
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You won't need any controllers to make Razor Pages work, as you can see in the `Startup.Configure(...)` method with the `app.UseEndpoints` call the framework does automatically the routing, so the URLs are mapped to your Razor .cshtml pages located in the `Pages` directory.

If you hadn't modified the contents of your `Pages` solution directory, then after launching the web app, you should see the `Pages\Index.cshtml`'s contents.

I suggest checking out the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) for Razor Pages for more details.

Comment: You're telling me that I have to add a bunch of things to an OOTB web project just to get it to run on a web browser? That doesn't seem right.

Comment: By no means under usual circumstances, e.g. if you create a new web app project based either on the ASP.NET Core Razor Pages or ASP.NET Core MVC web app templates in the latest VS2022 they work as intended OOTB. My answer specifically aims to provide a solution to serve Razor Pages content based on the op's current code that they've been provided in the question. Maybe the best answer to the op's question would be simply just to create a new project based on the ASP.NET Core Razor Pages template.

Comment: Interesting. I recently made a new ASP.NET Core Razor Pages web app project in VS 2022 v17.4 targeting .NET 6 and it did _not_ work OOTB. It only worked once I updated VS 2022 to v17.8 (debugging that issue is what led me to such questions/answers as these). FWIW, on that project, I _did_ have `services.AddRazorPages();` in my Program.cs page OOTB (since in .NET 6+ there is no Startup.cs file anymore).